# Intuition behind isolated types

Tags: model-theory

I learned that an $n$-type $\pi$ over a theory $T$ is isolated if there exists a formula $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $T \cup \exists \bar x \varphi$ is coherent and $T\vdash \forall \bar x (\varphi(x) \Rightarrow \psi(x))$ for all $\psi$ in $\pi$.

It seems to me that this says that $\pi$ is basically "finite": if a finite set of formulas $\varphi_i$ implies all the formulas in the type, then taking the conjunction of this set isolates $\pi$. Is this the way to apprehend isolated types?

For example, if $\pi$ is the complete 2-type $tp^{\mathbb C}(1,e)$, $\pi$ expresses all we can say about how $1$ and $e$ relates to each other in the language of rings, right? I think this is not isolated, but I don't know how to prove it formally. However, if $\pi$ is $tp^{\mathbb C}(1, \sqrt 2)$, then it seems to me that $y^2 - 2x$ isolates $\pi$, am I right?

Anyway, I don't have any intuition about what types really are. I would really appreciate any hints on how to apprehend them and how to use them!

Comment: Note that (as pointed out in a rejected edit) the "$\Leftrightarrow$" in the first paragraph should probably be "$\Rightarrow$". Otherwise only very trivial theories could have  isolated types because $\psi$ might be a tautology ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I just edited, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First: why do we have types? Because first-order logic is notoriously 'bad' with infinity.

Given any specific formula $\varphi(x)$ and a complete theory $T$ in some language $\mathscr{L}$, we either have $T \vdash \exists x\varphi(x)$ or $T \vdash \lnot \exists x\varphi(x)$. Whether or not any given formula has a realization in a model is entirely determined by the theory of the model. Of course, the same is true for any finite combination of formulas.

But what if we took an infinite collection of formulas? In general, the theory will tell you nothing about whether or not there is a common realization - unless your collection was not *really* infinite, meaning there is some single formula which implies each one in your set. More often, the existence of a common realization will depend on your specific choice of model.

A type is just a maximal consistent set of formulas in some fixed number of variables. Of course, every type will have lots of redundant formulas: you'll have every tautology, and every possible conjunction of formulas (though the maximality makes this worth it). In isolated types, everything is essentially redundant except for one formula (which implies everything else).

What would you do with types? Sometimes, you want to construct models of theories which either realize or omit a specific set of sentences - this happens a lot, and it's annoying to have to make the same compactness argument every time. It also provides an extremely useful way of comparing nonisomorphic models of a given theory, and counting how close those models are to being 'full'.

Comment: For your example: if you're taking the complete type over $\mathbb{C}$, your type *is* isolated because you have names for $1$ and $e$. If you're taking a type over the empty set, your type is not isolated, because it's generated by the formulas which say that there is no algebraic relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$, and there is no single formula that expresses this. To see why, just construct a model of the same theory with no transcendental elements.

Comment: Ok, so if I take $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ (the algrebaic closure of $\mathbb Q$) as a model of ACF_0 = Th($\mathbb C,+,-,\times,0,1$), then there is no transcendental elements over $\mathbb Q$, good! Thank you!